# oracle database filter with full outer join and coalesce intersect

Tags: oracle, join, coalesce

in a Oracle Database if I "shoot"

```
SELECT 
    RAP.IDPL,
    C41.TIP_COD_DESEU AS CD41,C41.STOC_VAL AS CANT41,
    C42.TIP_COD_DESEU AS CD42,C42.STOC_VAL AS CANT42,
    C43.TIP_COD_DESEU AS CD43,C43.STOC_VAL AS CANT43
FROM CHEST_UL CHT
    INNER JOIN UL_PUNCT_LUCRU rap
        ON cht.fk_id_raportor = rap.id
    FULL OUTER JOIN CH_41_TAB1 C41
        ON C41.FK_ID_CHEST = CHT.ID
    FULL OUTER JOIN CH_42_TAB1 C42
        ON C42.FK_ID_CHEST = CHT.ID
    FULL OUTER JOIN CH_43_TAB1 C43
        ON C43.FK_ID_CHEST = CHT.ID
    FULL OUTER JOIN CH_44_TAB1 C44
        ON C44.FK_ID_CHEST = CHT.ID
    FULL OUTER JOIN CH_5_TAB1 C5
        ON C5.FK_ID_CHEST= CHT.ID
WHERE COALESCE (C41.STOC_VAL,C42.STOC_VAL,
                  C43.STOC_VAL,C44.STOC_VAL,
                  C5.CANT_PREL)
        IS NOT NULL
```

the result is:

```
IDPL    CD1         CANT41  CD2         CANT42  CD3         CANT43
275522                      10.01.01    28.54       
275522                                          20.01.01    155
275522  10.01.01    102.766             
272343                      10.01.01    123     
272343                                          10.01.01    353
272343  10.01.01    102.766
```

what can I do to obtain a result like this:

```
IDPL    COD         CANT41      CANT42      CANT43
275522  10.01.01    102.766     28.54   
275522  20.01.01                            155
272343  10.01.01    102.766     123         353
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply group by IPDL:

```
SELECT 
    RAP.IDPL,
    MAX(C41.TIP_COD_DESEU) AS CD41, MAX(C41.STOC_VAL) AS CANT41,
    MAX(C42.TIP_COD_DESEU) AS CD42, MAX(C42.STOC_VAL) AS CANT42,
    MAX(C43.TIP_COD_DESEU) AS CD43, MAX(C43.STOC_VAL) AS CANT43
FROM CHEST_UL CHT
    INNER JOIN UL_PUNCT_LUCRU rap
        ON cht.fk_id_raportor = rap.id
    FULL OUTER JOIN CH_41_TAB1 C41
        ON C41.FK_ID_CHEST = CHT.ID
    FULL OUTER JOIN CH_42_TAB1 C42
        ON C42.FK_ID_CHEST = CHT.ID
    FULL OUTER JOIN CH_43_TAB1 C43
        ON C43.FK_ID_CHEST = CHT.ID
    FULL OUTER JOIN CH_44_TAB1 C44
        ON C44.FK_ID_CHEST = CHT.ID
    FULL OUTER JOIN CH_5_TAB1 C5
        ON C5.FK_ID_CHEST= CHT.ID
WHERE COALESCE (C41.STOC_VAL,C42.STOC_VAL,
                  C43.STOC_VAL,C44.STOC_VAL,
                  C5.CANT_PREL)
        IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY RAP.IDPL
```

Are you sure you need the FULL joins? Try changing all to LEFT, might return the same result.

If this can be simplified further depends on the actual PK/FK and data...

Comment: I don't think it works... [Error] Execution (2: 13): ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Comment: If this was your actual SQL it should work as-is, I just added the `GROUP BY RAP.IDPL` and the `MAX`